# VB script to select data from cells after particular number of rows in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I need to copy data from one sheet to another so that after selecting 1st row it will skip some 5 rows to fetch another data.

My initial data looks like this:

```
Row|Col A
  1|abc
  2|def
  3|ghi
  4|jkl
  5|mnp
  6|oqr
  7|stu
  ...
```

The code should result in output:

```
Row|Col A
  1|abc
  2|oqr
  ...
```

Comment: Welcome to S.O.! Does your data exist in an Excel file (meaning you'd like to use VBA, not VB.net)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will copy the first cell from sheet1 to sheet 2, and then every 5th one after that. e.g. 1,6,11,16 from sheet1 into 1,2,3,4 in sheet2

to change it to say 7 rows just change the multiplier on i to that value.

```
Cells(1 + i * 5, 1).
```

to change how many rows it copies change the following line

```
For i = 0 to 2
```

The code:

```
Sub copyData()

For i = 0 To 2
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1 + i, 1).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1 + i * 5, 1).Value
Next i

End Sub
```

if you want it to start at the currently selected cell use the following version:

```
Sub copyData()

For i = 0 To 2
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1 + i, 1).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(ActiveCell.row + i * 5, ActiveCell.Column).Value
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy. You solved my problem. I was able to complete my work within minutes. Please guide me for some tutorials in case of any future needs in excel.

Comment: What is it about the code you would like explained in more detail @Apoorv Rastogi ?

Comment: Like a beginner. I am a novice in this part. But I like coding. That's why, I asked for some e-books or websites where I can learn this stuff.

Comment: @ApoorvRastogi the only way to learn with coding is to try and fail, then try again, get a bit annoyed, and then suddenly it works! In terms of resources this site is great but also http://msdn.microsoft.com has good documentation about all the built in objexts and functions

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Dim N As Long
    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    N = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    s1.Range("A1").Copy s2.Range("A1")
    s1.Range("A6:A" & N).Copy s2.Range("A2")
End Sub
```